# Need to remove the prefix namespace in the output using XSLT

Tags: xslt, namespaces, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Is there any way on how to avoid populating the namespace of common: prefix in the output? And, this namespace should replace as a default namespace. I have this sample file:

INPUT:

```
<IntraConsignment xmlns="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/IntraConsignment" xmlns:common="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/InputCommon" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/IntraConsignment NewICO-in_v0_7.xsd" IntraListingsNbr="1">
<Representative>
    <common:RepresentativeID identificationType="NVAT" issuedBy="BE">9876941603</common:RepresentativeID>
</Representative>
<IntraListing SequenceNumber="1" ClientsNbr="1" AmountSum="1000.00">
    <Declarant>
        <common:VATNumber>9876941603</common:VATNumber>
    </Declarant>
    <Period>
        <Month>07</Month>
    </Period>
    <IntraClient SequenceNumber="1">
        <CompanyVATNumber issuedBy="DE">123456</CompanyVATNumber>
    </IntraClient>
</IntraListing>
</IntraConsignment>
```

And, I need to remove the common: prefix in the XML and the elements that doesn't have a prefix should have a ns2: prefix.

I have this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns2="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/IntraConsignment" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:common="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/InputCommon" xmlns="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/InputCommon" exclude-result-prefixes="xs xsi xsl common">
<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml" version="1.0"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="common:*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="ns2:{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My xslt is quite working but the namespace **xmlns="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/InputCommon"** did not appear in the output.

GENERATED OUTPUT:

```
<ns2:IntraConsignment xmlns:ns2="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/IntraConsignment" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/IntraConsignment NewICO-in_v0_7.xsd" IntraListingsNbr="1">
<ns2:Representative>
    <RepresentativeID xmlns="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/InputCommon" identificationType="NVAT" issuedBy="BE">9876941603</RepresentativeID>
</ns2:Representative>
<ns2:IntraListing SequenceNumber="1" ClientsNbr="1" AmountSum="1000.00">
    <ns2:Declarant>
        <VATNumber xmlns="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/InputCommon">9876941603</VATNumber>
    </ns2:Declarant>
    <ns2:Period>
        <ns2:Month>07</ns2:Month>
    </ns2:Period>
    <ns2:IntraClient SequenceNumber="1">
        <ns2:CompanyVATNumber issuedBy="DE">123456</ns2:CompanyVATNumber>
        <ns2:Amount>1000.00</ns2:Amount>
    </ns2:IntraClient>
</ns2:IntraListing>
</ns2:IntraConsignment>
```

EXPECTED:

```
<ns2:IntraConsignment xmlns:ns2="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/InputCommon" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/IntraConsignment NewICO-in_v0_7.xsd" xmlns="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/InputCommon" IntraListingsNbr="1">  
<ns2:Representative>
    <RepresentativeID identificationType="NVAT" issuedBy="BE">9876941603</RepresentativeID>
</ns2:Representative>
<ns2:IntraListing SequenceNumber="1" ClientsNbr="1" AmountSum="1000.00">
    <ns2:Declarant>
        <VATNumber>9876941603</VATNumber>
    </ns2:Declarant>
    <ns2:Period>
        <ns2:Month>07</ns2:Month>
    </ns2:Period>
    <ns2:IntraClient SequenceNumber="1">
        <ns2:CompanyVATNumber issuedBy="DE">123456</ns2:CompanyVATNumber>
        <ns2:Amount>1000.00</ns2:Amount>
    </ns2:IntraClient>
</ns2:IntraListing>
</ns2:IntraConsignment>
```

Answer (score 0):

With XSLT 1.0 the choice of namespace prefixes is left largely to the XSLT processor, whereas XSLT 2.0 is much more prescriptive. However, most XSLT 1.0 processors do the "right thing" even though they're not strictly required to.

You basically seem to have two rules:

(a) elements in namespace http://www.minfin.fgov.be/IntraConsignment should be copied using the prefix ns2:

```
<xsl:template match="x:*" xmlns:x="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/IntraConsignment">
  <xsl:element name="ns2:{local-name()}" namespace="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/IntraConsignment">
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

(b) elements in namespace http://www.minfin.fgov.be/InputCommon should be output in the default namespace:

```
    <xsl:template match="x:*" xmlns:x="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/InputCommon">
      <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/InputCommon">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
```